# What is the probability of two integers having identical values where each integer is summation of 4000 same or different integer values?

Tags: probability

There are two sets of 32 bit unsigned integer. Each set has 4000 numbers. Two sets could either be identical or they can different values. All 4000 numbers from each set are added and then the resulting sums from both sets are compared with each other. What is the probability of these two sums being identical? I am not good in math so haven't been able to try out any answer. My apologies in advance. Could you please help?

Thank you.

Comment: I think that the exact solution is extremely difficult to find. I would suggest a simulation. Considering the large sums that will occur, the probability of equality should be very low.

Comment: @Peter The probability would be too low for a simulation to work.

Comment: @TodorMarkov In fact this issue came in my mind. It should however be possible to find an upper bound (without a simulation).

Comment: 1. Do you really mean "two sets"? Or do you mean two lists? In particular, could one set consist of 4000 copies of the number "14"? Or must all 4000 of the numbers be distinct?  2. The question you've asked has an answer that depends on the particular sets (in a very complicated way). But if the *real* question is "I generate, using a uniform random number generator, two lists of 4000 32-bit unsigned ints, and sum each; what's the probability that the sums are equal?" then that's somewhat easier to answer. Is that actually your question?

Comment: @JohnHughes. I basically have multiple lists/sets of 4000 numbers. Each number/checksum is generated by running jenkins Hash on multiple IP addresses and MAC address. Now answer to second part of your first question. One set will never have 4000 identical numbers. Those 4000 number will always be distinct. However, there could be identical numbers between the sets/lists.  I think in Q 2 you have framed the question more accurately. So yes that is actually my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not a complete answer, but a start**

Warning: I know a bit of probability theory, but it's certainly not my strong suit. You're getting an answer here that's a lot like getting an answer to a calculus question from someone who just finished a first calculus course. I hope someone else can give a more authoritative answer based on what I've started here.

OK...with that caveat, here goes:

You've got 4000 32-bit natural numbers, uniformly distributed, but without repetition, in each of two sets $A$ and $B$. You're asking what is
$$
P(\sum_{a \in A} a= \sum_{b \in B}b)?
$$

I can't give you an exact answer, but I can give you a start on a very good approximation.

First approximation: I'm going to assume that the 4000 numbers in each set are picked uniformly randomly and *independently*, so that either set $A$ or set $B$ might contain duplicates. The probability of *no* duplicates in set $B$, for instance, is then
$$
\frac{N-1}{N} \cdot \frac{N-2}{N} \cdots \frac{N-3999}{N}
$$
where $N$ is shorthand for $2^{32}$. That works out to about 99.8 percent, so this is a very strong approximation.

Next, the random variable 
$$
S_A = \sum_{a \in A} a
$$
is *very* nearly normally distributed: if you made a histogram of the values of $S_A$, it'd look a lot like the normal distribution. (This follows from something called the Central Limit Theorem; I've added that to the list of tags for this question).

The random variable $a$ is uniformly distributed on integers between $0$ and $N-1$, so its mean is 
$$
m = \frac{N-1}{2}
$$
and its variance is (roughly)
$$
v = \frac{1}{12} (N-1)^2.
$$
Using independence of the individual numbers, we find that the mean of $S_A$ is $4000m$, and the variance is $4000v$. The same holds for $S_B$.

The difference $D = S_A - S_B$ is *also* a nearly-normal random variable, whose mean is therefore $0$, and whose variance is $8000v$. (See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalDifferenceDistribution.html).

We get a "collision" -- the values $S_A$ and $S_B$
 are the same -- exactly when $D = 0$.

Now $D$ is really a discrete random variable --- it takes on only integer values --- but we're approximating it with a continuous random variable -- let's call that $C$. I'm going to say that the probability that $D$ is $0$ is close to the probability that $C$ is between $-\frac12$ and $\frac12$.

Sadly, we can't just look this up. But we can define
$$
C' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{8000v}} C
$$
and observe that $C'$ is normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $1$, i.e., a normal random variable. And if $C$ is between $-1/2$ and $1/2$, then $C'$ is between 
$$
\pm\frac{1}{2\sqrt{8000v}}
$$

And the probability of THAT happening *is* written down. It's known as the "error function" (erf), and all we need to do is look at 
$$
erf(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{8000v}}).
$$
Fortunately, Matlab's willing to give us that value (or at least a good approximation of it), and it comes up with `3.3342e-07`, i.e., about $3 \times 10^-7$, which is about 1 in 3 million.

So: the odds of a collision (if my very rusty probability theory is right) come out to be about 1 in 3 million.

Comment: Thank you professor. Evidently I will never be learned enough to digest the full answer. Hence please consider the acceptance of the answer as my respect/regards.